# how to remove text after create token in TokenAutoComplete in xamarin android

Tags: android, xamarin.android, tags, autocompletetextview, tokenautocomplete

I won't remove text after creating token in TokenAutoComplete library in xamarin android.

bellow is my code

```
_searchView.Text= _searchView.Text.Replace(text, string.Empty);  
_searchView.PerformCompletion();
_searchView.AddObject(collaborator);
```

I also use below code

```
_searchView.ClearComposingText();
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't quite follow you.What kind of function are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to clear the text of the `AutoCompleteTextView`? If yes, you can try the following code:

```
 _searchView.SetText("",false);
```